# iOS swift UICollectionviewcell snapshot error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionviewcell, snapshot

When i tried to take snapshot a certain UICollectionViewCell in a UICollectionview which is a subview of View and share it on Facebook from my app..while Xcode throws

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

[please click here for screenshot of that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju4He.png)

Here is my function

```
func screenshotBSCell() {
        //Create the UIImage

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(bsCell.bounds.size.width, bsCell.bounds.size.height))
        ***self.bsCell.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)***
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        //Save it to the camera roll
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

        //share the image to Social Media
        let composeSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        composeSheet.setInitialText("Hello, Facebook!")
        composeSheet.addImage(image)

        presentViewController(composeSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: Debug and check for self.bsCell instance, is it nil ?

Comment: app crashing at the line         self.bsCell.layer.renderInContext((UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())!)

Comment: Where do you call `screenshotBSCell`? The problem is that `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` returns nil, which you then try to force unwrap (don't do that :)) resulting in a crash. So...it seems your call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` doesn't work as expected. As @Surjeet suggests...verify that your `bsCell` is not nil, and check the size of `bsCell` also to make sure it is valid.

Comment: I am calling inside the **cellForItemAtIndexPath** as **cell.shareBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(screenshotBSCell), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)**

Answer (score 0):

```
func screenshotBSCell( sender:AnyObject) {
        //Create the UIImage
        let indexpath = NSIndexPath.init(row: sender.tag, section: 0)

        self.bsCell = colletctionview!.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath ) as! bsCell
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height))
        ***self.bsCell.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)***
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        //Save it to the camera roll
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

        //share the image to Social Media
        let composeSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        composeSheet.setInitialText("Hello, Facebook!")
        composeSheet.addImage(image)

        presentViewController(composeSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

make the func like this.it will solve your problem.When you called this function it create the cell for you so its not getting nil cell

Answer (score 0):

It is now working with minimal changes. Thanks everyone!

```
 func screenshotPulseCell(sender: UIButton) {

    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(plCell.frame.size)
    self.plCell.contentView.layer.renderInContext((UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

    //share the image to Social Media
    let composeSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    composeSheet.setInitialText("My Pulse!")
    composeSheet.addImage(image)

    presentViewController(composeSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```